# How to setup coding enviornment over the network

Tags: development-environment

I need to setup the Team Coding Environment i.e. Two or more people, over the local network can code together on a project (PHP coding). How should I get started...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to people to work on the *same* files.

Let both of them work on their own files (locally or on separate folders on a server) and have them use a VCS such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/). This ensures conflicting modifications do not simply overwrite someone else's code but have to be properly resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using any kind of [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (Git, SVN ...) and an IDE which support this SCM ([netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/), eclipse).

Git and [Github](https://github.com/) seems to be the trend of the moment. You should give it a look